# surface integral of a function over a boundary of sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\int\int (x+y+z)dS$, where $S$ is the boundary of the unit ball $B$; i.e $S$ is the set of $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

I parametrized usually using $x=sin\theta cos\phi,y=sin\theta sin\phi,z=cos\theta$, where $0\le \theta \le \pi$, and $0\le \phi \le 2\pi$.

But in this way the integral comes out to be $0$. I know for sure surface area cann't be $0$. In the hint for question it is written that "use the symmetry of the problem".

I am not sure how symmetry comes into play here and if at all it does then i am not seeing how.

Please help me out

Comment: Is there a final value for this integral? I found one which is $4\pi/3$.

Comment: I mean if $S$ is the **outer** surface of that ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this integral is in fact zero. Look at the problem this way: For any point on the unit ball where $x + y + z$ is positive, you can find another point on the ball where the integrand is negative, and of the the same magnitude, simply by rotating the ball 180 degrees. Hence, the integral should be zero since you are integrating an odd function. You ought to be able to prove this intuition by carrying out the integral just as you have described in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't the integral be 0? For example, by symmetry across the x=0 plane,
$$
    \int\int x dS = 0.
$$
The same argument applies to each of the three integrals.